# Maxima: How to define built-in functions?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

Is there a way to define built-in functions in `Maxima`?

I have a function which I would like to use in several .wxm files without defining them in every file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the functions in a file, let's say it is named `foo.mac`, and then call `load("foo.mac")` to load the functions into Maxima or wxMaxima.

Note that `load` needs to be able to find `foo.mac`. If `foo.mac` is not in one of the usual folders, you can help `load` find it in a few different ways:

(1) State the fully-qualified path, e.g. `load("/Users/myfolder/myfunctions/foo.mac")`.

(2) Put your folder on the list of folders to search and then call `load`. E.g.

```
push ("/Users/myfolder/myfunctions/###.mac", file_search_maxima);
load ("foo.mac");
```

Note that `file_search_maxima` is a global variable which tells all the folders in which `load` searches.